# Include X-Forwarded-Port header on requests through an Istio proxy

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I'm looking at enabling Istio across a cluster. Inside the cluster are several services that generate links for clients to follow. Since enabling the istio sidecars the links are being generated incorrectly.

A request will be made to service a at something like `http://service-a.foo.svc.cluster.local:7001/x/y/z`, but the response from that will be missing the port on any generated links. i.e. `http://service-a.foo.svc.cluster.local/x/y/z`

It looks like this is because the envoy proxy sidecar is not including an X-Forwarded-Port header, which the service needs to construct a viable link.

Is it possible to configure the sidecars to include that header? [Envoy docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-port) suggest some config that is required to add the header, but I don't see how to do that in Istio.

We've had some success with VirtualService resources where the X-Forwarded-Port is manually specified, but we'd have to roll that out to every affected service, and it seems like a workaround rather than a proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have made good progress with this. First I should signpost to some links that really helped.

An issue was raised on envoyproxy's github about this exact type of issue. [One of the comments talks about](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3732#issuecomment-1178745033) fixing this in an Istio deployment using an EnvoyFilter.

I also used [this link](https://karlstoney.com/2021/07/07/using-envoyfilters-to-debug/) to debug the headers that were coming through the sidecar. Very useful to see what was going on.

In that comment, the user adds an X-Forwarded-For header specifically for the Spring Actuator endpoints that require it.

I've adapted that answer and applied a filter to the workload in question. I check for the presence of the X-Forwarded-For header, and only add it if one wasn't already specified. In debugging this, I saw many requests coming into the pod with the header set, and envoy happily passes that along - it just doesn't seem to add the header itself.

Here is my filter:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: eo-cloud-envoy-fiter
  namespace: foo
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: cre-services
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value: # lua filter specification
          name: envoy.filters.http.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
            inlineCode: |
              local function isempty(s)
                return s == nil or s == ''
              end
              
              local function print_request_details(request_headers)
                local authority = request_headers:get(":authority")
                local path = request_headers:get(":path")
                print(string.format("Authority = %s", authority))
                print(string.format(Path = "%s", path))
              end
              
              local function add_forwarded_port(request_handle)
                local request_headers = request_handle:headers()
                local forwarded_port_header = request_headers:get("x-forwarded-port")
                if isempty(forwarded_port_header) then
                  local localAddressWithPort = request_handle:streamInfo():downstreamLocalAddress()
                  local t={}
                  
                  for str in string.gmatch(localAddressWithPort, "([^"..":".."]+)") do 
                    table.insert(t, str)
                  end
                  print(string.format("x-forwarded-port header is missing, adding it with value: %s", t[#t]))
                  request_handle:headers():add("X-Forwarded-Port", t[#t])
                else
                  print("Request already had an X-Forwarded-Port header. No change necessary") 
                end                
              end
              
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                print_request_details(request_handle:headers())
                add_forwarded_port(request_handle)
                print("")
              end
```

Here is the log output from the Istio proxy, showing a request having the header added using the port that was provided:

> 2023-07-07T13:08:54+01:00
> /agent-service/devtenant/agents/admin/permissions?profile=SystemAdmin:
> 2023-07-07T13:08:54+01:00 x-forwarded-port header is missing, adding
> it with value: 7001